# angular/angular-material: replacing a HTML slider doesn't update its ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-ng-model

```
 $scope.$watch("checkbox", function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
     var newmax = calcNewMax();
     var slider = angular.element(document.querySelector("#slider"));
     var parent = slider.parent();  
     slider.remove();
     var newSlider = '<md-slider id="slider" flex="100" class="md-warn" md-discrete ng-model="size" step="10" min="100" max="' + newmax + '" aria-label="rating"> </md-slider>';
     parent.prepend($compile(newSlider)($rootScope));
     $scope.size = 500;
                });
```

I am using the `md-slider` of angular material.
What I actually want is to update the max value of the slider based on a user choice via checkbox.
My first attempt with just setting a new value for the `max` attribute didn't work (also didn't work for the `aria-valuemax`).

So I decided to just remove the complete slider and replace it.
The above code works.

But what doesn't work is that when I add the new slider, `ng-model`, which is bound to `$scope.size` seems not to be synced anymore (I have a label which binds to that value and it doesn't update). Of course `$apply()` doesn't work as I am already in a `$watch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do what you wanted in your first attempt, and it works:

```
<md-slider step="1" md-discrete min="0" max="{{max}}" ng-model="value"></md-slider>
<md-checkbox ng-model="max" ng-true-value="20" ng-false-value="{{baseMax}}">
       max 20
</md-checkbox>
<md-checkbox ng-model="max" ng-true-value="40" ng-false-value="{{baseMax}}">
       max 40
</md-checkbox>
<md-checkbox ng-model="max" ng-true-value="60" ng-false-value="{{baseMax}}">
       max 60
</md-checkbox>
```

Please take a look at this plunker and compare with your solution
https://plnkr.co/edit/BAM5ToIzZDUoqWPcQlWA?p=preview

Comment: Awesome @Patryk, my mistake was to add the max value via `.attr("max", newmax)`, it hadn't occured to me I could just use angular directly :) Thanks!